# Increase idle timeout of AWS serverless websocket

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

We are trying to use serverless Websocket feature of API Gateway on AWS platform.
During initial observation, we have seen like the idle connection timeout for such websocket is 10 minutes. We have a requirement where we need to increase this time to 30 minutes so that the websocket connection should not close.

Is there any setting or alternate way of increasing this default idle time?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the table under *API Gateway quotas for configuring and running a WebSocket API* in this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html), you can see that increase of idle timeout is currently not supported.

My solution was to send a heartbeat (without any data since we just need to interact through the websocket to let API Gateway know that the connection is not idle) through the websocket every 5 minutes, and it has been working well.